# ngResource TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a working api currently, but somewhere in the connection to it through angular Im getting something wrong.

**Working api route**

```
// Routes for users
router.route('/user')
  // GET (Read) all users
  .get(UserController.list)
  // POST (Create) a new user
  .post(UserController.create);
```

**UserController.authenticate**

```
// Creates a user
module.exports.create = function(req, res) {

  // console.log(req.body); => undefined ( this is where the error comes in! )

  var user = new User();
  user.name = req.body.name;
  user.email = req.body.email;
  user.password = req.body.password;
  user.save(function (err, result) {
    if(err) {
      if(err.code == 11000)
        res.json({ success: false});
      else
        res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.send(err);
    }
  });
  res.json({ success: true });
};
```

**Factory used by controller below**

```
.factory('User', ['$resource', function($resource) {
   var User = $resource('/user', {}, {
                all: { method: 'GET', isArray:true }
              });

   return User;
 }]);
```

**Part of the form with controller used in the view (Simplified)**

```
<div ng-controller="RegistrationCtrl">
  <form ng-submit="createUser(user)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.name">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.email">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.password">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
</div>

.controller('RegistrationCtrl', ['$scope', 'User',
   function($scope, User) {

  $scope.user = new User();

  $scope.createUser = function(user) {

    // console.log(user) => Object { name: "test3", email: "test3", password: "test3", $resolved: true }

    user.$save(function() {
    // user data save do something...
    });
  };

}]);
```

**Working view with controller that uses same service**

```
 <div class="container" ng-controller="UserCtrl">
   <h1>Users</h1>
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.name}}</li>
   </ul>
 </div>

 .controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', 'User',
    function ($scope, User) {

    $scope.users = [];

    // immediately executing function
    $scope.users = User.all()

 }]);
```

What should I do? Obviously I am doing something wrong with *ngResource*. Im pretty new to angular.

Comment: Maybe you need a bodyparser ?

Comment: Currently I have: `server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); server.use(bodyParser.json());` in my node app

Comment: Yet, if `req.body` is undefined, it's not working

Comment: It seems like the problem is in the User factory definition. What does the save method look like?

Comment: @AustinMullins I have not defined it. I thought `$save` was built in? The factory is defined as you see it.

Comment: [This](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/) is the only online example I found that actually creates a new object using ngResource, and they do two things differently. The full endpoint path (including an ID parameter) is defined in the resource URL, and they call the "class level" save method, not the "instance level". So, `User.save` instead of `user.$save`.